# How to normalise the filename to just the mp3 filename with no path ? Ruby

Tags: ruby, tdd

I am trying to solve a lab but I am not sure what is going on. What I have to do is that I have to import some file names (.mp3's) from a directory and then use the file name to make some objects. I am still stuck at getting the filenames from the directory. The Test is asking me to

**"Normalise the filename to just the mp3 filename with no path"**

the test is as follows:

```
  it 'normalizes the filename to just the mp3 filename with no path' do
  test_music_path = "./spec/fixtures/mp3s"
  music_importer = MP3Importer.new(test_music_path)

  expect(music_importer.files).to include("Action Bronson - Larry Csonka - indie.mp3")
  expect(music_importer.files).to include("Real Estate - Green Aisles - country.mp3")
  expect(music_importer.files).to include("Real Estate - It's Real - hip-hop.mp3")
  expect(music_importer.files).to include("Thundercat - For Love I Come - dance.mp3")
end
```

My Code is:

```
class MP3Importer
 attr_accessor :path

 def initialize(path)
  @path = path
 end

 def files
  Dir.chdir(@path)
  filename = Dir.glob("*.mp3")
  filename
 end
end
```

This is also passing these two tests:

```
  describe '#initialize' do
it 'accepts a file path to parse mp3 files from' do
  test_music_path = "./spec/fixtures/mp3s"
  music_importer = MP3Importer.new(test_music_path)

  expect(music_importer.path).to eq(test_music_path)
end

describe '#files' do
it 'loads all the mp3 files in the path directory' do
  test_music_path = "./spec/fixtures/mp3s"
  music_importer = MP3Importer.new(test_music_path)

  expect(music_importer.files.size).to eq(4)
end
```

But the error it creates is:

```
Failure/Error: expect(music_importer.files).to include("Action Brons
 Errno::ENOENT:
   No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - ./spec/fixtures/mp3s
```

To be honest I have no idea what Normalising the filename to mp3 filename with no path means? It is very misleading. I already have the array of filenames at variable filename in my #files method.

My questions are:

1. What does the statement "Normalise the filename to just the mp3 filename with no path" mean ? what does the test want me to do?
2. What is happening in the code posted?
3. Why is the error pointing to the directory? When the directory does have the required file?

Comment: I think it means that given a path "./spec/fixtures/mp3s/some_path.mp3" it will just give you "some_path.mp3". We have [File.basename](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-basename) for that by the way.

Comment: Okay. But if that's the case then the path that is being set at #initialize does not have the filenames in it. Its just a path till the mp3 directory "./spec/fixtures/mp3s" .. where as `File.basename` will work if the full path to the file is given.

Comment: You could try making the method return  `Dir.glob("#{@path}/*.mp3")`. Other than that I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary remark : post all the code and only the minimum of code, so that we can copy-paste and execute it to reproduce the error. An RSpec tag and the version of RSpec would also be useful in this case.

When I execute your code :

```
   No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - ./spec/fixtures/mp3s
 # ./lib/t_a.rb:14:in `chdir'
```

the error is in the statement at line 14 :

```
Dir.chdir(@path)
```

This gives a clue that `chdir`does not find the requested subdirectory in the current working directory. Why ? Add a trace to display the current working directory :

```
def files
    puts "in files, path=#{@path}"
    puts "wd=...#{Dir.getwd.sub(/.*ruby(.*)/, '\1')}"
    current_dir = Dir.getwd
    Dir.chdir(@path)
...
```

and run the tests (I'm working in `...devl/ruby/zintlist/mp3_importer`) :

```
$ rspec

MP3Importer
  #initialize
    accepts a file path to parse mp3 files from
  #files
in files, path=./spec/fixtures/mp3s
wd=.../zintlist/mp3_importer
    loads all the mp3 files in the path directory
  #xxxx
in files, path=./spec/fixtures/mp3s
wd=.../zintlist/mp3_importer/spec/fixtures/mp3s
```

and you see the difference :

```
wd=.../zintlist/mp3_importer
wd=.../zintlist/mp3_importer/spec/fixtures/mp3s
```

When executing `files`, you have a side effect : the current directory is changed. In the second execution of `files`, `Dir.chdir` starts searching in the current directory left by the first execution, that is `.../mp3_importer/spec/fixtures/mp3s`, and `mp3s` of course does not contain `./spec/fixtures/mp3s`, hence the error `No such file or directory`.

The solution is to restore the directory which is current when entering the method :

```
def files
    puts "in files, path=#{@path}"
    puts "wd=...#{Dir.getwd.sub(/.*ruby(.*)/, '\1')}"
    current_dir = Dir.getwd
    Dir.chdir(@path)
    filenames = Dir.glob("*.mp3")
    Dir.chdir(current_dir)
    filenames
end
```

Then the trace shows that it has been restored :

```
wd=.../zintlist/mp3_importer
...
wd=.../zintlist/mp3_importer
```

You may already know that if you process a file inside a `File.open ... do ... end` block, the file is closed when the block exits. The same works for restoring the current directory. From [The Pickaxe](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0) Dir.chdir :

> If a block is given, it is passed the name of the new current
>   directory, and the block is executed with that as the current
>   directory. The original working directory is restored when the block
>   exits.

Given these files :

```
#file t.rb

class MP3Importer
    attr_accessor :path

    def initialize(path)
        @path = path
    end

    def files
#        puts "in files, path=#{@path}"
#        puts "wd=#{Dir.getwd.sub(/.*ruby(.*)/, '\1')}"
        filenames = Dir.chdir(@path) do | path |
#            puts path
            Dir.glob("*.mp3")
        end
        puts "names=#{filenames}"
        filenames
    end
end
```

.

```
# file t_spec.rb

require 't'

RSpec.describe MP3Importer do
    let(:test_music_path) { "./spec/fixtures/mp3s" }
    let(:music_importer)  { MP3Importer.new(test_music_path) }

    describe '#initialize' do
        it 'accepts a file path to parse mp3 files from' do
            expect(music_importer.path).to eq(test_music_path)
        end
    end

    describe '#files' do
        it 'loads all the mp3 files in the path directory' do
            expect(music_importer.files.size).to eq(4)
        end
    end

    describe '#xxxx' do
        it 'normalizes the filename to just the mp3 filename with no path' do
            expect(music_importer.files).to include('f4.mp3')
        end
    end
end
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0rc1 (2016-12-12 trunk 57064) [x86_64-darwin15]
$ rspec -v
RSpec 3.6.0.beta2
  - rspec-core 3.6.0.beta2
  - rspec-expectations 3.6.0.beta2
  - rspec-mocks 3.6.0.beta2
  - rspec-support 3.6.0.beta2
$ rspec

MP3Importer
  #initialize
    accepts a file path to parse mp3 files from
  #files
names=["f1.mp3", "f2.mp3", "f3.mp3", "f4.mp3"]
    loads all the mp3 files in the path directory
  #xxxx
names=["f1.mp3", "f2.mp3", "f3.mp3", "f4.mp3"]
    normalizes the filename to just the mp3 filename with no path

Finished in 0.00315 seconds (files took 0.09868 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures
```

All tests are green.

As the method return value is that of the last executed expression, you can simplify `files` like so :

```
def files
    Dir.chdir(@path) do | path |
        Dir.glob("*.mp3")
    end
end
```

> What does the statement "Normalise ... mean ?

I don't know. I suppose it's collecting only the files whose name correspond to a certain pattern, here `*.mp3`.

What I can say is that RDoc takes input file names from the command line and passes them to a routine called `normalized_file_list`:

```
# file rdoc.rb
  ##
  # Given a list of files and directories, create a list of all the Ruby
  # files they contain.
  #
  # If +force_doc+ is true we always add the given files, if false, only
  # add files that we guarantee we can parse.  It is true when looking at
  # files given on the command line, false when recursing through
  # subdirectories.
  #
  # The effect of this is that if you want a file with a non-standard
  # extension parsed, you must name it explicitly.

  def normalized_file_list(relative_files, force_doc = false,
                           exclude_pattern = nil)
    file_list = []

    relative_files.each do |rel_file_name|
      next if rel_file_name.end_with? 'created.rid'
      next if exclude_pattern && exclude_pattern =~ rel_file_name
      stat = File.stat rel_file_name rescue next

      case type = stat.ftype
      when "file" then
        next if last_modified = @last_modified[rel_file_name] and
                stat.mtime.to_i <= last_modified.to_i

        if force_doc or RDoc::Parser.can_parse(rel_file_name) then
          file_list << rel_file_name.sub(/^\.\//, '')
          @last_modified[rel_file_name] = stat.mtime
        end
      when "directory" then
        next if rel_file_name == "CVS" || rel_file_name == ".svn"

        created_rid = File.join rel_file_name, "created.rid"
        next if File.file? created_rid

        dot_doc = File.join rel_file_name, RDoc::DOT_DOC_FILENAME

        if File.file? dot_doc then
          file_list << parse_dot_doc_file(rel_file_name, dot_doc)
        else
          file_list << list_files_in_directory(rel_file_name)
        end
      else
        warn "rdoc can't parse the #{type} #{rel_file_name}"
      end
    end

    file_list.flatten
  end

  ##
  # Return a list of the files to be processed in a directory. We know that
  # this directory doesn't have a .document file, so we're looking for real
  # files. However we may well contain subdirectories which must be tested
  # for .document files.

  def list_files_in_directory dir
    files = Dir.glob File.join(dir, "*")

    normalized_file_list files, false, @options.exclude
  end
```